# Understanding non homogeneous recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a particular and then the general solution for the recurrence relation
$a_n = 7\cdot a_{n−1} − 30 \cdot 2^n$

Trying to understand this equation.... We have been given a general formula for this format of the equation $2^n\cdot p = 7 \cdot 2^{n-1} - 30 \cdot 2^n$ but don't know how to plug these in. Could someone help please? Many thanks

Comment: What is $p$? ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this as
$$
a_{n+1}=7a_n-30\cdot2^{n+1}
$$
and compute
$$
a_{n+2}=7a_{n+1}-30\cdot2^{n+2}
$$
But 
$$
30\cdot2^{n+2}=2\cdot(30\cdot2^{n+1})=2(7a_n-a_{n+1})
$$
so we get
$$
a_{n+2}=7a_{n+1}-2(7a_n-a_{n+1})
$$
or
$$
a_{n+2}-9a_{n+1}+14a_n=0
$$
which is a linear recurrence relation and the roots of the characteristic polynomial are $2$ and $7$.